# Is it possible to use media queries with a php file?

Tags: php, css, media-queries

I am trying to make my site responsive and my media query was working but now it isn't. I made some changes and didn't use version control because I'm an idiot. Now I've taken out all the changes and the old media query isn't working, can anyone see why? I've included my css and the html I'm applying it to.

```
.contact_form {
    margin: auto auto auto 27%;
}

.slides p {
    margin: 2%;
    text-align: center;
}

.slides h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.required {
    color: red;
}

.privacy p {
    width: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .slides h2 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 10% auto auto auto;
    }
    .slides h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .contact_form {
        margin: 2%;
    }

    .privacy p {
        width: 90%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    .tablet_content {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Html

```
<body>
<div class="banner">
        <header>
            <div id="ytWidget"></div>
            <script src="https://translate.yandex.net/website-widget/v1/widget.js?widgetId=ytWidget&pageLang=en&widgetTheme=dark&autoMode=true" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <br clear = "all">
            <a href="index.html">
                <h1>Laura Pohl Web Solutions</h1>
                <h2>User Based Web Design</h2>
            </a>
        </header>
    </div>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">About</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Founder.html">My Story</a>
                <a href="kittens.html" class="active">Mascots</a>
            </div>
        </div>
  <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Portfolio</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="custom web design.html">Custom Web Design</a>
                <a href="Wordpress.html">Wordpress</a>
                <!--<a href="Under Construction.php">Wix</a>
                <a href="Under Construction.php">Squarespace</a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
  <a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
  <a href="Contact Us.php">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
    <main class="site-content">
        <div class="gradient"> 
            <br>
            <div class="slide">
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="slides">
                        <h1>Contact Questionnaire</h1>
                        <h2>If you’d like to work with me, I can’t wait to get started! Your first step is to fill out the custom form below.</h2>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "contact_form">
                    <form name="form4" action="Contact Us.php" method="post">
                        <input type = "hidden" name ="recipient" value ="1">
                        <input type = "hidden" name ="subject" value ="Contact Survey">
                        <input type = "hidden" name ="print_blank_fields" value ="1">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_pid" value="154040">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_fid" value="A7QPIZEA">

                        <table  class ="contact_table">
                            <tbody>
                                <!--Row 1-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions">Name:<span class="required">*</span></td>
                                        <td colspan = "6"><input name="sender" id="name" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box required" title="Please type your name." required></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 2-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions">Email:</td>
                                        <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderEmail" type="text" maxlength="30" class ="input_text_box"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 3-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions">Phone:</td>
                                        <td colspan = "6"><input name="senderPhone" type="text" id="textfield2" maxlength="30"class ="input_text_box"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 4-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 5-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 6-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">Preferred Method of Contact?</td>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="preferredContact" value="phone" id="PreferredContact_0"></td>
                                        <td colspan = "2" width = "30%">Phone</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 7-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="preferredContact" value="email" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                        <td colspan = "2">Email</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 8-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 9-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 10-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions" rowspan="2">Would you like a response?<span class="required">*</span></td>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="Yes" id="PreferredContact_2"></td>
                                        <td colspan = "2">Yes</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>                     
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 11-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="Response" value="No" id="PreferredContact_3"></td>
                                        <td>No</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 12-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 13-->   
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 14-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions" rowspan="7">What would you like to talk about?<span class="required">*</span></td>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="web_design"></td>
                                        <td colspan = "5">Website Design</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 15-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="re_design"></td>
                                        <td colspan="5">Website Re-Design</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 16-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="consultation"></td>
                                        <td colspan="6">Schedule a Consultation</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 17-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="quote"></td>
                                        <td colspan="6">Request a Quote</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 18-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="suggestions"></td>
                                        <td colspan="6">Suggestions</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 19-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="problems"></td>
                                        <td colspan="6">Site Problems</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 20-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="radio" name="topic" value="something_else"></td>
                                        <td colspan="6">Something Else</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 21-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 22-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 23-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class = "questions" style="vertical-align:middle;">Message Text: </td>
                                        <td colspan = "6" style="text-align: left">
                                            <textarea rows = "5" name="message" maxlength="800" id="Comments" class ="input_text_box" required></textarea>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 24-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 25-->  
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan = "7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                <!--Row 26-->
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit" style = "float:left"></td>
                                        <td colspan = "5">&nbsp;</td>
                                        <td><input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" style = "float:right"></td>
                                    </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br clear = "all">
        <br>
        <div class="privacy">
                    <hr style="width: 20%;">
                        <p>I take your privacy seriously. I will never share any of your 
                        information with anyone outside legal requirements. You will never be spammed or marketed
                        to by any of my partners.</p>
                        <hr style="width: 20%;">
        </div>
    </main>
    
    <div class="big_screen_content">
        <footer>
        <!--start footer-->
            &copy; November 30, 2020 &middot; <a href = "Contact Us.php">Laura Pohl</a> &middot; Billerica, MA <!--Copyright signature-->
        </footer>
        <!--end footer-->
    </div>
```

Comment: What HTML tags are you trying to apply these media queries to? Please provide all the code necessary for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: PHP is simply a server side language that outputs to HTML. So, yes, you can certainly use Media Queries with PHP - since it's CSS. If you couldn't, I would guess half the websites in the world wouldn't work.